# Laravel eloquent whereTime less hours

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table `events`:

- `id`
- `user_id`
- `reception_day` (date format) // 2023-11-20
- `time_from` (time format) // 11:00:00
- `is_available` (bool 1 or 0)

I need to output all records in which `reception_day >= current day`, but if it is today's date, then the current time should be less than 1 hour from `time_from` (`time_from < current time`).

```php
Event::whereDate('reception_day', '>=', $now)
    ->where('is_available','=',1)
    ->orderBy('reception_day')
    ->orderBy('time_from');
```

Is it preferable to do this at the database level?

Comment: Can you please share as to what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using additional `orWhere` for today's date.

```php
$events = Event::where(function ($query) use ($now) {
    $query->whereDate('reception_day', '>', $now->toDateString())
          ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($now) {
              $query->whereDate('reception_day', '=', $now->toDateString())
                    ->whereTime('time_from', '>', $now->addHour()->toTimeString());
          });
})
->where('is_available', '=', 1)
->orderBy('reception_day')
->orderBy('time_from')
->get();
```

In this query:

The where clause has two parts:

The first part checks for events with `reception_day` greater than the current day.
The second part checks for events with today's date but ensures that `time_from` is greater than the **current time plus one-hour**. This is achieved by using the whereTime condition.
The `orderBy` clauses are as you provided, ordering by `reception_day` and then by `time_from`.

You would need to do few modification to code if above does not work as I have not tried to execute.

Comment: ChatGPT answers are not allowed

Comment: Thank, this is what i need.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam
While I appreciate your perspective, I want to clarify that seeking assistance, even from tools like ChatGPT, is a common practice in problem-solving and knowledge enhancement. As a seasoned expert in Laravel and PHP, I leverage various resources to provide accurate and insightful solutions. The goal is to enhance the overall quality of answers. If you have specific concerns about the answer, I'm more than willing to address them and contribute to a constructive discussion.

Comment: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)